# TeXShop and High Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: mactex, texshop

With the new MacOS, "High Sierra", I found an inconvenience while typesetting a document with TeXShop: just after compiling (Cde T), the Preview window becomes black for a very short time (fleeting). It's visually annoying. I wonder if other users have the same behaviour on their Mac (I have a MacBook Pro, one year old)? For the rest everything ok !
AG

Comment: My MacBookPro ("late 2013" model) runs MacOS 10.13.1 as well. Running TeXshop and MacTeX2017, I am unable to reproduce the issue you are encountering.

Comment: How do you have the Preview set up? E.g., Single- or Multi-Page, etc. Is it a long document? Where in the document is the page you are viewing? Is your MacBook Pro a Retina version? Any other information you can apply. There have Benny’s reports of a gray flash but not black.

Comment: If it's the same flash that others have seen with High Sierra (especially when re-compiling and viewing later pages in a long document) it's a problem with PDFKit in High Sierra and Apple needs more people to complain to them to get action.

Comment: Hi Herb, thanks for your swift answer. The Default Page style as alway been Multi-Page, it's a 10 pages documents, and I have a Retina 15 inch (2880x1800), this fleeting is very short, and appear after each compilation. But strange enough, when I open for the first time an existing tex file, at the first compilation, no fleeting, then if I make another change, this fleeting appears, at at each change in the source file...

Answer (score 2):

This problem is fixed in TeXShop 3.94 and 3.95. It is caused by new behavior of PDFKit and is visible when an application opens a pdf to a page number higher than page one. Fixing the problem within PDFKit is not possible; instead a fix requires additional application code.

Comment: Quite happy with the fix, I suppose the default delays has been shorten from 3.94 to 3.95, anyway on my MacBookPro, you can't nearly notice it !